# how to use onload to run javascript in a search box that removes the keyword "script"

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I dont know how to do it. Any tips? My project is due tomorrow

```
<body onload="loadImage()">; <script> "function loadImage() { alert("Image is loaded"); }" </script>
```

I am trying to replace the alert(1) by actual script without using the word script because it is filtered...

```
<body onload="loadImage()">;
"function loadImage() {
    alert("Image is loaded");
}"
```

I want to run something like this, like this function but I cannot use the word script. I am taking EECS388: Computer Security at the University of Michigan. And I am trying to do an Cross site scripting alias xss. The search removes the keyword "script" so it is not possible to run javascript unless it is in some sort of tag (body or img)

Comment: could you explain more, with code you tried so far.

Comment: This is what I tried: <body onload="loadImage()">;

"function loadImage() {
    alert("Image is loaded");
}"

Comment: I use alert to test that this works in a firefox browser

Comment: XSS challenge? You'll have to give us more info. Also don't post code in the comments, edit your question.

Comment: You should either inline the code in `onload="function(){...}"` (inlining is generally bad) or import a js file outside your html file

Comment: @Gibolt do you mean doing this: <body onload="loadImage(){ alert("Image is loaded") }">

Comment: No, try `onload='function(){alert("Image is loaded");}'`. Keep in mind that this is bad form

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to avoid the script tag, try:

```
<body onload='function(){alert("Image is loaded");}'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your function is not defined when body load it load after body loaded. I mean prepare your function top of your body

```html
<script>
function loadImage()
{
alert("Image is loaded"); 
} 
</script>
    <body onload="loadImage()">
    hello
    </body>
```

**Update**

Solution is put your

```
<--example.js-->
function loadImage()
{
alert("Image is loaded"); 
}
```

function in another js file.

in your HTML Declare top of your body like this

```
<script src='example.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<body onload="loadImage()">
        hello
</body>
```

Comment: hey thank you! but how can you do it without the word ' <script> '? it is filtered

Comment: if i understand correct you want to alert without <script></script> does <link> tag work for you?

Comment: I cannot use link to refer to another js file I have to submit only one file for this project